# Create and Delete record when adding new object in Ember

Tags: ember.js

i want to be able to create/delete record in my model any time i add or delete item (transaction) inside the single invoice

The problem is i don't know how how to do it with my current template

```
    <tr>
        <td><button {{action add transaction}}>Add</button></td>
        <td><button {{action delete transaction}}>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>  


    <tr>
      <td>{{input type="number" value=quantita}}</td>
      <td>{{view Em.Select prompt="test" contentBinding="controllers.tariffa.content" optionLabelPath="content.name" optionValuePath="content.id" selectionBinding="controllers.tariffa.selectedTariffa" }}</td>
      <td>{{input value=totale}}</td>
      <td>{{view Em.Select prompt="test" contentBinding="controllers.iva.content" optionLabelPath="content.name" optionValuePath="content.value" selectionBinding="controllers.iva.selectedIva" }}</td>
      <td>{{input value=ivamount}}</td>
      <td>{{input value=risultatofinale}}</td>
    </tr>
```

These are the actions i would add in the Index controller

```
  actions:{
    add: function(transaction) {
    this.get('store').createRecord('transaction', attrs);
    }
  }


  actions:{
    delete: function(transaction) {
    this.get('store').deleteRecord('transaction', attrs);
    }
  }
```

Is this possible to achieve it with my view? How?

I have reproduced the issue here http://jsbin.com/xuzemi/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

The events bubble up from the view to the controller, from there you can perform any operations you want with the `store`.

And to obtain the values from your input fields you use binds.

```
  actions:{
    add: function() {
      var title = this.get('title');
      console.log('title: ' + title);
      var invoice = {title: title}
      this.store.createRecord('invoice', invoice);
      this.set('title', 'zero');
    }
  }
```

I edited your fiddle, it should put you in the right track: http://jsbin.com/qurupi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Thanks for putting me in the right direction , i probably can explain better but i wanted to achieve the creation of new object only for the transactions included in the invoice, if you can correct my jsbin it would be great to accept the answer http://jsbin.com/moduro/2/edit

Comment: I do not understand. Ask something specific. For future questions, strip out business logic, any validations and everything you can. Make it as easy as possible for anyone trying to help, you'll get more answers.

Comment: What i am trying to explain is that i want to add and delete any transition with the controller functions

Comment: Okay, what is stopping you? What did you try and why it didn't work? Got an error message? Is the relationship `DS.hasMany` what is troubling you?